# Windows Command to detect and remove text in a file

Tags: windows, command-line, text, sed

I have an ascii file and in there somewhere is the line:
BEGIN
and later on the line:
END

I'd like to be able to remove those two lines and everything in between from a command line call in windows. This needs to be completely automated.

EDIT: See [sed in Vista - how to delete all symbols between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425864/sed-in-vista-how-to-delete-all-symbols-between) for details on how to use sed to do this (cygwin has sed).

EDIT: I am finding that SED could be working but when I pipe the output to a file, the carriage returns have been removed. How can I keep these? Using this sed regex:

/^GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution$/,/^EndGlobalSection$/{
 /^GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution$/!{
 /^EndGlobalSection$/!d 
 }
 }

.. where the start section is 'GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution' and the end section is 'EndGlobalSection'. I'd also like to delete these lines as well.

EDIT: I am now using something simpler for sed:

/^GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution$/,/^EndGlobalSection$/d

The line feeds are still an issue though

Comment: If the answers to your previous question were unsatisfactory, then say so. This new question is equivalent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425864/sed-in-vista-how-to-delete-all-symbols-between

Comment: Any other ideas about hte line feed issue? Its possibly because of the pipe to the new file:  > newfile
I need it to pipe each line including the newline char

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, what I use these days is a scripting language that plays nicely with windows like Ruby or Python for such tasks.  Ruby is easy to install in windows and makes problems like this child's play.

Here's a script you could use like:
**cutBeginEnd.rb myFileName.txt**

```
sourcefile = File.open(ARGV[0])

# Get the string and do a multiline replace
fileString = sourceFile.read()
slicedString = fileString.gsub(/BEGIN.*END\n/m,"") 

#Overwrite the file
sourcefile.pos = 0                
sourcefile.print slicedString             
sourcefile.truncate(f.pos)
```

This does a pretty good job, allows for a lot of flexiblity, and is possibly more readable than sed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 1-line Perl command that does what you want (just type it from the Command Prompt window):

```
perl -i.bak -ne "print unless /^BEGIN\r?\n/ .. /^END\r?\n/" myfile.txt
```

Carriage returns and line feeds will be preserved properly.  The original version of `myfile.txt` will be saved as `myfile.txt.bak`.

If you don't have Perl installed, get [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/?psbx=1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to delete the entire GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution section using a C# regular expression:

```
// Create a regex to match against an entire GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) section so that it can be removed (including preceding and trailing whitespace).
// The symbols *, +, and ? are greedy by default and will match everything until the LAST occurrence of EndGlobalSection, so we must use their non-greedy counterparts, *?, +?, and ??.
// Example of string to match against: "    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) ...... EndGlobalSection     "
Regex _regex = new Regex(@"(?i:\s*?GlobalSection\(TeamFoundationVersionControl\)(?:.|\n)*?EndGlobalSection\s*?)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```