# Library compiled without debugging information

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, sfml, pdb-files

I just compiled SFML from source with VS 2013, and after testing it out with a sample project i got tons of warnings like "PDB 'vc210.pdb' was not found with ##### or at #####, linking object as with no debug info". PDBs did get created, but they were not moved to install directory. So now I have a vc210.pdb for every compiled lib. 
Is there a way to have needed all the debug info without having each library in a separate directory?

Comment: Quoting error messages *accurately* is very, very important.  And no, that is not possible, the program database is later needed to merge the final PDB when the linker creates the executable from the libraries.  Don't move files.

Comment: there are 40 warnings and the hashed out parts are just obj names and test project directory. I does compile successfully though.

Comment: Use z7 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052406/pdb-files-with-libraries-in-visual-studio-10/17052896#17052896