# How to make windbg load pdb of static library

Tags: c++, windbg

I have a binary a.dll which includes a static library b.lib in it.
I try to debug the logic in a.dll using windbg. 
a.pdb can be loaded into the windbg session so that I can see detail info about a.dll's variable, function, line of code. 
But how can I load b.pdb into the windbg session? without b.pdb loaded, I can not see detail info when logic goes into b.lib's function.

Here is a call stack sample :

```
039fefdc 32e9eac3 0000000a 01ec4570 039ff1b0 a!b_function::ParamDirType (FPO: [0,0,0])
039ff214 32eeba62 047c5790 32f1d26c 039ff258 a!a_function+0x485 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: thiscall) [source code path @ 1874]
```

b_function is implemented in b.lib, b.pdb is not loaded, so I can not know the code line.

Tnx for anyone who can help on this.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575298/static-library-debug-symbols