# Move *.pdb file for static library without breaking references - LNK4099

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdb-files

I built a 3rd party static library in a folder called `<libraryBuildDir>` and copied the resulting *.lib file into my projects folder structure. Along with the *.lib, I also placed the *.pdb file. Then I deleted `<libraryBuildDir>`, assuming it's no longer needed. This is what worked for other libraries before and it follows [what seems to be a common practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575298/static-library-debug-symbols).

However, when I build my project in debug configuration I get many LNK4099 warnings like this (roughly translated):

```
<myLib>.lib(<someObjFromTheLib>.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB "<myLib>.pdb" was not found alongside "<myLib.lib>" or "<myBuildDir>". Linking without debug info
```

I verified that the *.pdb file is there right next to the *.lib file.
As a test, I placed it right into the build directory, as suggested by the warning. Now I get many LNK4204 like this:

```
<myLib>.lib(<someObjFromTheLib>.obj) : warning LNK4204: "<myBuildDir>\<myLib>.pdb" is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
```

I followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843883/how-to-remove-warning-lnk4099-pdb-lib-pdb-was-not-found) to extract one of the object files that appeard in my warnings, (`<someObjFromTheLib>.obj`). I noticed that the extracted *.obj file did not contain a `Debug$T` section.

So apparently when I copied the *.pdb file from `<libraryBuildDir>` to my project, I broke some links to other debug symbol files that are now not available anymore, because I deleted `<libraryBuildDir>`. This makes me think that my whole process is wrong.

**My goal**: Compile the static library with debug symbols and move the finished *lib file to another project. Then compile the other project and include the full debug symbols from the static library.

**How can I move a pdb file from a temporary library build directory to another directory without breaking any references?**

(Sidenote: I'm compiling Crypto++ v8.2.0 using cmake and the *.pdb file is called `cryptopp-object.pdb` whereas the library is called `cryptopp-static.lib`. This goes against the convention that *.lib and *.pdb have the same name, but it is how Crypto++ is configured and I don't want to change that if possible. However, the *.lib file seems to expect the correct name for its pdb file so I assume that this is fine.)

(Also: `lib /list <myLib>.lib` lists a lot of *.obj files and only some of those appear in my LNK4099 warnings, whereas others don't. I don't know if that means they're simply not used in my project or if they have all debug information available.)

Comment: The linking is done from the linker includes folders, are the pdbs there? Is the pdb and lib from the same “build“? Are you mixing Release and Debug builds?

Comment: You can use the /Fd compile option to put the program database in a directory that you are not going to delete.  But certainly much easier to just not delete that directory.

Comment: @Robert Andrzejuk Yes, the pdb files are in the include folders right next to the actual lib file. And no, I did compile the lib first and copied the pdb from another build, assuming that a build is deterministic and produces the same output everytime (no settings were change in between). Turns out, If I recompile and copy the lib and pdb from the exact same run, the problem seems to disappear. Why on earth are the results not deterministic?

Comment: What do You mean deterministic? The lib and pdb have to be copied together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out, If I recompile and copy the lib and pdb from the exact same run, the problem seems to disappear.
>
> Why on earth are the results not deterministic?

a) Because the PDB contains a timestamp and that timestamp will rarely be the same on different builds

b) Because builds can be multi-threaded nowadays, thus leading to different results, depending on what is compiled first.

c) The "same" code (with regards to behavior) could produce a different AST, e.g. if you just moved methods around.

> How can I move a pdb file from a temporary library build directory to another directory without breaking any references?

It should be possible as long as the PDB matches the build. However, consider building into the desired directory [using the /Fd option for the PDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fd-program-database-file-name?view=vs-2019) and [/Fo option for the OBJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score -2):

**Solution**: Builds are not deterministic. The *.pdb and *.lib files have to be from the exact same "build".