# GNU sed In Windows and Line Termination Character

Tags: sed, gnu

It is a bit confusing as to what character(s) are used in Windows/DOS version of GNU sed to terminate a line.  In particular, what is the newline (\r\n vs \n) char used to join 2 lines after an N command?

What I want is to create a script that combine C++ source lines that is using the line continuation character \ syntax.

e.g.

```
int \
a=\
10;
```

should be combined into this by my script:

```
int a=10;
```

Obviously I should use something like the "N" command and then the 's' command to substitute anything in the pattern space that looks like \ followed by a newline char with an empty string.  But in Windows is this newline char \r\n or \n after an "N" command?

And should I use \\\r\n or \\\n to search for the lines with the line continuation pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about the Windows/DOS version of sed, but if it is like the version in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652652/sed-preserve-line-endings), it will magically turn `\r\n` into `\n` for processing.  Like in the linked question, you will probably need an extra `s/$/\r/` to put the `\r` back in.  I tested

```
sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta; s/$/\r/'
```

in Cygwin, and it seems to work.

Comment: if I could give more thumbs up, I would.

Answer (score 0):

> And should I use \\r\n or \\n to search for the lines with the line continuation pattern?

Why not use both? i.e. in `sed`

```
s/\r\?\n//g
```

which will match both `\r\n` or `\n`. `?` might not need to be escaped if you're using ERE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about \r\n vs \n when using GNU sed on Windows. The program opens the file in "text" mode which treats \r\n as if it were a \n character on Unix systems.

The '-b' or '--binary' option can be used on Windows machines when you want to **disable** this mode, and treat the \r as a **non-end-of-line character**, such as searching for a '\r' in the "middle" of a line (i.e. terminated by '\n')

Comment: And what is used to join two lines when the 'N' command is used?