# Pattern Matching in a csv file and appending to matched lines

Tags: python, unix, csv

I want to extract those lines a csv file which match a Pattern and then append the same Pattern to the end of each extracted line as a newly added column of the csv file.

file.csv

`file.csv`

```
/var/log/0,33,New file,0
/var/log/0,34,Size increased,2345
/abc/Repli,11,New file,0
/abc/Repli,87,Size Increase,11
```

`In above file file.csv, I executed`

```
sed -n -i"" '/Repli/ s/$/,Repli/p' file.csv
```

This deletes remaining lines, which I do not want.

Comment: You might want to add some more details to this question. Maybe post some code of what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want to append the pattern (which could be a regex?), or the value that the pattern matches?

Comment: I have tried. But every time it adds a control character ^M and in excel it shows in next row instead of next column

Comment: @mhawke I want to append based on matching with the pattern. For ex. Match /var/log/0/, if found, append BE in last column of matched lines

Comment: Are there other cases, e.g. if match /var/log/1 append XYZ ?

Comment: Right. This is exactly the case. sed -i"" 's/\r//; /pattern/ s/$/,pattern/' file.csv is working perfect for single word patterns, but for paths it is giving me sed syntax error

Answer (score 0):

#### Extracting only the lines that match a pattern and modifying them

To select only lines containing pattern and then add pattern as a new column at the end of the line:

```
awk '/pattern/ {print $0 ",pattern"}'  file.csv >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ file.csv
```

Or,

```
sed -b -n -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv
```

#### Keeping all lines but modifying those that match a pattern

```
awk '/pattern/ {$0=$0 ",pattern"} 1'
```

Or,

```
sed -b -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/' file.csv
```

#### Remove Windows line endings while keeping all lines and modifying those that match a pattern

```
sed -i"" 's/\r//; /pattern/ s/$/,pattern/' file.csv
```

#### Remove Windows line endings while keeping all lines and modifying those that match a pattern containing slashes

Suppose that the pattern contains slashes like `/var/log/abc/file/0/`.  Then:

```
sed -i"" 's/\r//; \|pattern| s|$|,pattern|' file.csv
```

For example:

```
sed -i"" 's/\r//; \|/var/log/abc/file/0/| s|$|,/var/log/abc/file/0/|' file.csv
```

Comment: I Tried awk '/pattern/ {print $0 ",pattern"}' file.csv. But it gives me the pattern appended at the beginning of the line and not the end. Also, I require to have changes in the file in place. Using awk is just giving me changes output.

Comment: See updated answer for changing the file in place.  `print $0 ",pattern"` will put the pattern at the end of the line.  If something else happened when you tried it, please document exactly what you did with sample input, the code, and sample output.

Comment: sed -n -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv adds a control character before adding the pattern and thus when I open this csv in excel, the last column actually gets displayed in next row. But I want to display it in same row.

Comment: That should not happen.  Please document exactly what you did with sample input, the code, and the output in which the control character appeared.

Comment: sed -n -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv was run on the file due to which in file.csv only lines containing pattern remained and other lines deleted. Also ^M was added before pattern in each matched line as '^M, pattern'

Comment: OK.  That would appear to mean that you are on Windows and your `sed` [has a bug in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652652/sed-preserve-line-endings).  As a work around, try: `sed -b -n -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv`

Comment: I am working on bash shell on RHEL5.1. Running sed -b did not work on it giving error. Also, I want only matched lines to append in the file. The rest of the lines should remain as it is. In current usage of sed -n -i"" '/pattern/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv, remaining lines not matching the pattern get deleted.

Comment: The ^M characters indicate Windows line endings.  If they are appearing on RHEL, that indicates a problem with `file.csv`.  Run it through a dos2unix converter.

Comment: sed -i"" 's/\r//; /pattern/ s/$/,pattern/' file.csv seems to have worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you could please answer a small query as well that if pattern is complex like "pattern=/var/log/abc/file/0/", then how can I match it using sed. I tried simply sed -n -i"" '//var/log/abc/file/0/ s/$/,pattern/p' file.csv gave me error

Answer (score 0):

`I found a solution to match paths using sed. I did it through escap character and it worked.`

`Pattern="\/var\/log\/Model\/1\/"`
`Module=BE`
`sudo sed -i"" "s/\r//; /$Pattern/ s/$/,$Module/" resultFile.csv`

Worked Fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet appends the pattern in case if a match is found. If no match found just prints the line,

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /pattern/) print $0",pattern"; else print $0;}' file.csv
```