# Removed semicolon from a line in php.ini using shell command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'd like to removed a semicolon from one of these lines in the php.ini using bash shell command (perhaps using `sed`). How would I do that?

```
;extension =php_curl.dll    
 ; extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension = php_mbstring.dll
;extension= php_openssl.dll
```

I intentionally added spaces here and there.

What I've tried:

```
sed -e "s/^;extension\s=\sphp_gd2\.dll$/extension=php_gd2\.dll/" -i php.ini
```

This just places everyting into a single line:

```
;extension =php_curl.dll ; extension=php_gd2.dll;extension = php_mbstring.dll;extension= php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes a semicolon at the beginning of a line that has one or more spaces on both sides

`sed '/php_gd2/s/^\s\s*;\s\s*//' php.ini`

You can specify which php extension you want to operate on by putting it in between slashes at the beginning. Then it will run the substitute command only on the lines that have the specified extension

To be even more selective,

`sed '/^\s*;\s*extension\s*=\s*php_gd2.*\.dll/s/^\s\s*;\s\s*//' php.ini`

Comment: Perhaps I was not too clear. I'd like to specify which php extension I want to enable.

Comment: Great! But shouldn't I check if the line starts with `; extension` and ends with `<extension-name>.dll` in case the text is inside e.g. a comment.

Comment: That can be done with `sed '/extension\s*=\s*php_gd2.*\.dll/s/^\s\s*;\s\s*//' php.ini`

Comment: Superb! Thanks Thomas

Comment: `sed -b '/^\s*;\s*extension\s*=\s*php_gd2\.dll/s/^\s\s*;\s\s*//' -i php.ini` - Added `-b` because of [line ending issue on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11508669/1772200). Also added `-i` to make changes on the file instead of just printing it out.