# Remove optional semicolon at line start with sed

Tags: sed, sh, posix

I need to uncomment and edit this line using `sed`:

```
root@host:~# cat $CONF | grep "pm\.max_requests"
;pm.max_requests = 500
```

Tried this, but nothing worked:

```
root@host:~# sed -i "s/^;?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
root@host:~# sed -i "s/^\;?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
root@host:~# sed -i "s/^(;)?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
root@host:~# sed -i "s/^(;?)pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
```

Here's what did work:

```
root@host:~# sed -i "s/^;pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
```

Problem is, the command has to work even if a semicolon isn't there.

I know I can start with something like below, but I was hoping I can have it done all in one line.

```
sed -i "s/#;pm\.max_requests/pm.max_requests/g" ${CONF}
```

---

Checked if this is a duplicate, but all I could find was [Removed semicolon from a line in php.ini using shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848502/removed-semicolon-from-a-line-in-php-ini-using-shell-command)

Comment: POSIX BRE (the regex flavour used by `sed` by default) doesn't support `?` as a meta-character. It may support `\?` and it does support `\{0,1\}`, but you will probably want to use ERE instead by using the `-E` flag (modern GNU sed & BSD sed) or the `-r` flag (older GNU sed). Using the `*` quantifier would be another alternative since there would be no obvious harm in removing multiple existing `;` characters at the start of the line

Comment: "Some implementations support `\?` and `\+` as an alternative syntax to `\{0,1\}` and `\{1,\}`, but `\?` and `\+` are not part of the POSIX standard." ([source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html))

Comment: See https://ideone.com/VYEbQq, use `sed -i -E "s/^;?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` by default uses the Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) regex flavour which does not parse `?` as the "0 or 1" quantifier. Your commands fail as they try to match an inexistant literal `?` character.

Your alternatives are the following :

- some implementations support `\?` as the "0 or 1" quantifier, although it's not POSIXly defined

  ```
  sed -i "s/^;\?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
  ```
- you can use the equivalent `\{0,1\}` quantifier

  ```
  sed -i "s/^;\{0,1\}pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
  ```
- You could use the `*` quantifier instead of `?`, which would lead to possibly removing multiple consecutive `;` characters

  ```
  sed -i "s/^;*pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
  ```
- you can switch to the Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) regex flavour, using `sed -E` for BSD `sed` or modern GNU `sed` and `sed -r` for older GNU `sed`. With this flavour, the `?` quantifier will work as you expected it to.

  ```
  sed -iE "s/^;?pm\.max_requests *= *[^ ]*/pm.max_requests = 512/" ${CONF}
  ```

Comment: All true but the script should be `sed -Ei 's/^;?(pm\.max_requests *=).*/\1 512/' "$CONF"`.

Comment: Thank you so very much @Aaron, the asterisk worked!