# Remove a repetitive string in a list with bash

Tags: string, bash, cygwin

How would you remove a string that repeats in most lines of a list with bash?

E.G.

My list looks like this:

```
Rex Rocket Steam Game
Magdalena Steam Game
FLASHOUT 2 Steam Game
Falcon
Girls Like Robots Steam Game
The Land Of Lamia Steam Game
Aeon Command
```

And I want to remove all the "Steam Game" string from all the lines that end that way.

I'm super rusty, this looks so easy but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `Steam Game` is a hard-coded string, or is it supposed to be deduced from the input?

Answer (score 4):

There's many options, `sed` is probably the simplest.

```
$ sed 's/Steam Game$//' foo.txt        
Rex Rocket 
Magdalena 
FLASHOUT 2 
Falcon
Girls Like Robots 
The Land Of Lamia 
Aeon Command
```

You asked for `"Steam Game"` to be removed not `" Steam Game"`.  If you want the space also removed, add a space to the regex: `'s/ Steam Game$//'`.  Or use `'s/  *Steam Game$//'` if there are more than one space.

Comment: This leaves a space at the end of every line it was removed from.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Now the problem is when I redirect that command to a  file it removes all newlines from every row. Any ideas?

Comment: That's really odd.  How exactly are you running it?  You're not using backticks are you?

Comment: Linux? MacOS?  Is this a windows file?

Comment: I'm using cygwin in Win10. Didn't know this could affect the outcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652652/preserve-line-endings - add `--binary` to the command line.  I think what you're seeing is the `\r\n` converted to `\n`. If you're using notepad to check, notepad ignores `\n`.  Try [Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/).

Comment: For some reason, adding --binary makes the command not to work. However, you're right. Opened the same file with WordPad and the newlines are there. No idea why Notepad doesn't respect them. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @te0k : `'m using cygwin in Win10.` That information usually goes in the question.