# git filter not 'unmodifying' file

Tags: git, sed, git-filter

I am working with an IDE which produces a version in some generated, but strongly required files of libraries. So there is an issue if I want to use the library with multiple versions or I see a load of changes which are in fact senseless.

**Summary:** I want to ignore a *single* line of one or multiple files which I thought git's filters are the right approach. I am able to `grep` for the relevant line without a problem as one might see reading further.

Long story short, I set up a git filter to revert any modification to the version in the header file. (Please note that there might be different modifications which are relevant in this file.)

```
[filter "ignore-version"]
    smudge = cat %f || cat
    clean  = git ls-files %f --error-unmatch >&- 2>&- \
              && sed \"/version/c $(git show HEAD:%f | grep version)\" || cat
```

(I added escaped line breaking for better reading and changed the word to match for simplicity. In the original version there are no collisions possible.)

1. `git ls-files` checks if the file is already in the repository (currently *HEAD*)

1.1 if present, `sed` will do the dirty work to replace the whole line with the already tracked one

1.2 if not, `cat` will do nothing but go ahead (this should ensure a not yet tracked file will not get lost)

So far, it works. (I can live with the fact that the filter silently converts all *CRLF* to *LF*...)

**Problem**: The fixed file is marked as modified by git, although the most recent file of the repository and the filtered version are binary equal. I checked this using *kdiff* as separate tool.

---

**Edit 1**: Here is some output which shows the equality of the two file versions:

```
$ git show HEAD:file.txt | md5sum
9f95c28cebe4f45b8efb7b0ae64dfa56
$ cat file.txt | md5sum
894e7d1b28180b7a193bf3cdd6ceaacb
$ cat file.txt | git ls-files file.txt --error-unmatch >&- 2>&- \
              && sed \"/version/c $(git show HEAD:file.txt | grep version)\" 
              || cat | md5sum
9f95c28cebe4f45b8efb7b0ae64dfa56
```

---

**Edit 2:** Additionally, the output of the difference...

```
$ git diff file.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Please note that the checked in version of this file contains only *LF* as by the previous commit. Note also that the setting `core.autocrlf` is *true* without having anything but the filter specification in the `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: I reproduced this on a Linux machine using a repository from scratch and ... it worked. The same command does it! So there is clearly a problem using git on Windows machines and line breaking. I tried all git configurations but none did work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628305/windows-git-warning-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-is-that-warning-tail-backwar

Comment: @Gimby I should have been following this warning, you were right, although the explanation behind the link was not the solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508669/6385043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. The file of question was in a strange state, it seems like the checked out version had unix style line endings which is not right regarding the git configuration (check out windows style, commit unix style). After *staging* this particular file it was instantly removed from staging area without any mention and is now considered unchanged. So I think git cleaned the working directory file during staging (line endings) and now it works.

Sorry for the noise.

---

Steps to completly check the problem:

```
git init
echo "version=0.1" > file.txt
echo "*.txt filter=ignore-version" > .gitattributes
git config --local filter.ignore-version.clean 'git ls-files %f --error-unmatch >&- 2>&- \
    && sed -b "/version/c $(git show HEAD:%f | grep version)" || cat'
git config --local filter.ignore-version.smudge 'cat %f || cat'
git add file.txt .gitattributes
git commit -m "initial commit"
# -----
echo "version=0.2" > file.txt
git status
```

Status should not report any changes. It worked for me using bare repositories on both, Linux and Windows.