# How to replace a search text from a given line number using sed or awk

Tags: shell

A file mytext.txt has in line number 20

```
<mytext=SO svn=myrepo number=2.1.0>
```

using SED or AWK I would like to change the line number 20 of mytext.txt to

```
<mytext=SO svn=myrepo number=2.1.6>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: replace an entire line in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Is it always line # 20 that you want to change OR certain pattern needs to be matched before replacement?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==20{$0="NEW TEXT"}7' file
```

next time do some man sed/awk before post.

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

```
sed -ri '20 s/2.1.0/2.1.6/g' file
```