# Replace line in text file with line from other text file

Tags: bash, replace

My question is a variant of the following one:

[bash: replace an entire line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file)

The problem there was to replace the Nth line of a file with a given string (a replacement line). In my case, I can't just type the replacement line, but I have to read it from another file.

For example:

textfile1:

```
my line
your line
his line
her line
```

textfile2:

```
our line
```

I want to replace the 2nd line of textfile1 with the line from textfile2.

I thought I could just read the textfile2

```
while IFS= read SingleLine
```

etc. and then use `$SingleLine` as the replacement line, but I failed... Depending on the type of quotes I used (please excuse my ignorance...) I ended up replacing the line in question with the text **$SingleLine** or with **SingleLine** or just getting an error message :-[

I am sure you can help me!!

EDIT about the solution: 
I went for the inline solution with the small change

```
sed '2d;1r textfile2' textfile1 > newfile1
```

To replace the Nth line, the solution would be (see comments on accepted solution for explanations)

```
sed 'Nd;Mr textfile2' textfile1 > newfile1
```

with N the desired line number and M=N-1.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '2d;1r file2' file1
my line
our line
his line
her line
```

To make it inline edit:

```
sed -i.bak '2d;1r file2' file1
```

Comment: Thanks! But... could you explain the '2d;1r' part? In particular: what if I wanted to replace the 4th line?!

Comment: `2d` is deleting 2nd line and `1r file2` is replacing file2 content after end of line 1. To replace 4th line use: `sed '4d;3r file2' file1`

Comment: Great! Thanks, that was really quick! :-) I went for the inline solution with the small change `sed '2d;1r textfile2' textfile1 > newfile1` to save a new file without destroying the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the `sed` solution [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009837/970195) posted. Here is an alternate in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 
    (( ++linenum == 2 )) && while read -r line; do 
        echo "$line"
        continue 2    # optional param to come out of nested loop
    done < textfile2
    echo "$line"; 
done < textfile1
```

or using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==2{if((getline line < "textfile2") > 0) print line; next}1' textfile1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this script or directly from terminal?
If this is a script. You can try to store file 2 into variable
`fromfile2=$(cat textfile2)`
Then replace your textfile1 with 
`sed -i "s/your line/$fromfile2"`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to specify that I cannot type the second line of the original file either. What do I write then instead of "your line" in the above? I tried  sed "2s/*/$fromfile2 textfile1 > textfile1new  but it didn't work ("unterminated substitute in regular expression").