# BSD sed: extra characters at the end of d command

Tags: sed, bsd

I use sed command on mac OS, following is the text.

```
$ cat pets.txt 
This is my cat
  my cat's name is betty
This is your dog
  your dog's name is frank
This is your fish
  your fish's name is george
This is my goat
  my goat's name is adam
```

when I run: (BSD sed)

```
$ sed '3,6 {/This/d}' pets.txt
```

It show error:

```
sed: 1: "3,6 {/This/d}": extra characters at the end of d command
```

what's wrong with it? when I use `gsed(GNU sed)`, it works well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put a semi-colon after the `d` (the spaces shown are optional):

```
sed -e '3,6 { /This/d; }' pets.txt
```

BSD `sed` is fussier about the layout than GNU `sed`. There are a number of GNU extensions that are not part of BSD `sed`, and this is one.  The semi-colon isn't the universal solution to problems, though it does solve many of them. You could also spread the commands out over multiple lines, or put them in multiple `-e` options, or various other 'tricks'.

Comment: This is the real answer, the `-i ''` is another problem.

Answer (score 120):

For anyone who found this question due to a similar error message, but caused by an attempt to *in-place edit* on **Mac OS X**

As per https://github.com/lmquang/til/issues/18:

> OS X requires the extension to be explicitly specified. The workaround is to *set an empty string*:

```
$ sed -i '' 's/megatron/pony/g' /path/to/file.txt

         ^^
```

`man sed`:

> `-i extension`
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension. **If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.** It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

So, there seems to be an issue on Mac OS X when `extension` is omitted, and so you have to supply `-i` with an empty string (`''`).

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024/23614:

> If using FreeBSD or OS/X, replace `-i` with `-i ''`.

Comment: Still running into this on OS X in 2023. Thank you @user664833

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on the GNU extension which lets `{` and `}` be part of a single expression.  To make it portable, you need to ugly it up a bit:

```
sed -e 3,6{ -e /This/d -e } pets.txt
```

You could also put the commands into a file, one per line:

```
3,6 {
  /This/d
}
```

For more on why this is, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed