# grep for a line in a file then remove the line

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, grep

```
$ cat example.txt
```

Yields:

```
example
test
example
```

I want to remove 'test' string from this file.

```
$ grep -v test example.txt > example.txt 
$ cat example.txt 
$
```

The below works, but I have a feeling there is a better way!

```
$ grep -v test example.txt > example.txt.tmp;mv example.txt.tmp example.txt 
$ cat example.txt 
example
example
```

Worth noting that this is going to be on a file with over 10,000 lines.

Cheers

Comment: The real question here is: "Why does `grep -v test example.txt > example.txt` make the file `example.txt` empty?! Is it not that `>` is used to delete a file's content and add new content while `>>` is used to append content? Then why does `>` delete the content and does not add a new one?

Comment: @71GA because of how bash command processing works - the ">" will open (and also clear) the file first and then grep reads from it. But it wont read anything, because the file is empty because of the ">"

Comment: maybe you try regexp with -v option it works

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're doing it the right way but use an `&&` before the mv to make sure the grep succeeded or you'll zap your original file:

```
grep -F -v test example.txt > example.txt.tmp && mv example.txt.tmp example.txt
```

I also added the `-F` options since you said you want to remove a string, not a regexp.

You COULD use `sed -i` but then you need to worry about figuring out and/or escaping sed delimiters and sed does not support searching for strings so you'd need to try to escape every possible combination of regexp characters in your search string to try to make sed treat them as literal chars (a process you CANNOT automate due to the position-sensitive nature of regexp chars) and all it'd save you is manually naming your tmp file since sed uses one internally anyway.

Oh, one other option - you could use GNU awk 4.* with "inplace editing". It also uses a tmp file internally like sed does but it does support string operations so you don't need to try to escape RE metacharacters and it doesn't have delimiters as part of the syntax to worry about:

```
awk -i inplace -v rmv="test" '!index($0,rmv)' example.txt
```

Any grep/sed/awk solution will run the in blink of an eye on a 10,000 line file.

Answer (score 25):

You could use sed,

```
sed -i '/test/d' example.txt
```

`-i` saves the changes made to that file. so you don't need to use a redirection operator.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
             edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Comment: what if i was looking for t/e/s/t ?

Comment: `sed -i '/t\/e\/s\/t/d' example.txt`

Comment: Or use a different delimiter.

Comment: Whichever delimiter `X` you pick has the same problem/question: `what if I was looking for tXeXsXt?`.

Comment: [Note that this does not work on macOS / BSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081375/bsd-sed-extra-characters-at-the-end-of-d-command)

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep` command will immediately cause the output file (`example.txt`) to be opened for writing. That deletes ("truncates") the file's contents, so the file is empty when it starts being read.

The `sponge` command from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils) package is designed for situations like this, e.g.

```
grep -v test example.txt | sponge example.txt
```

This works since `sponge` will buffer all of its input, and only open the given file (`example.txt`) for writing once it's finished receiving input. Note that this may be a bad idea for files which are larger than your RAM!

[Moreutils is available in most distros.](https://repology.org/project/moreutils/versions)