# Awk replace entire line when match is found

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, debian

I have the following code:

```
function replaceappend() {
    awk -v old="^$2" -v new="$3" '
        sub(old,new) { replaced=1 }
        { print }
        END { if (!replaced) print new }
    ' "$1" > /tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /tmp/tmp$$ "$1"
}

replaceappend "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" "Port" "Port 222"
```

It works perfectly but I am looking to modify it so it replaces the entire lines contents rather than just the matching text.

At the moment it would do this:

```
Port 1234 -> Port 222 1234
```

I want it to be work like this:

```
Port 1234 -> Port 222
```

I closest code I can find to do this is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145377/1738522):

```
awk 'NR==4 {$0="different"} { print }' input_file.txt
```

This would replace the entire line of the match with the new content. How can I implement this into my existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, use a regular expression for that which you want to replace:

```
replaceappend port.txt "Port.*" "Port 222"
```

Here you are replacing Port (if it starts the line, as per your function definition) plus whatever follows until the end of the line with "Port 222".

**EDIT**: To make this part of the function instead of requiring it in the call, modify it to

```
function replaceappend() {
    awk -v old="^$2.*" -v new="$3" '                                                                                                        
        sub(old,new) { replaced=1 }                                                                                                         
        { print }                                                                                                                           
        END { if (!replaced) print new }                                                                                                    
    ' "$1" > /tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /tmp/tmp$$ "$1"
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to integrate this into the function instead. Would it be this? ```awk -v old="^$2.*" -v new="$3" '```? I've added the period and the star as per your answer.

Comment: I always want the entire line to be replaced so I think your example with the asterisk is correct, but just that I want it on the function itself and not the command to call the function

Comment: Yes, that would work fine.  I'll put that in the answer as well.

Comment: Please note, that this does not work when $3 contains a `&` char, as that implicitly references your match and thus mangels your desired replacement. That needs to be masked as `\&`. But not sure, how that can be accomplished within the AWK though.

Answer (score 3):

Just change:

```
sub(old,new) { replaced=1 }
```

to:

```
$0~old { $0=new; replaced=1 }
```

or:

```
sub(".*"old".*",new) { replaced=1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the entire line you can simplify your function. To avoid problems with metacharacters in the variables you pass to awk, I would suggest using a simple string search too:

```
awk -vold="$2" -vnew="$3" 'index($0,old)==1{f=1;$0=new}1;END{if(!f)print new}' "$1"
```

`index` returns the character position of the string that you are searching for, starting at 1. If the string `old` is at the start of the line, then the line is changed to the value of `new`. The `1` after the block is always true so every line is printed (this is a common shorthand for an unconditional `{print}` block).

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) has pointed out in the comments, the variables you pass to awk are still subject to some interpretation: for example, the string `\n` will be interpreted as a newline character, `\t` as a tab character, etc. However, this issue is much less significant than it would be using regular expressions, where things like a `.` would match any character.

Comment: Great simplification; a hypothetical caveat (not a problem with the OP's example): passing a value via `-v ...` is still subject to _some_ interpretation by `awk`: try `awk -v v='a\nb' 'BEGIN { print v  }'`.