# how to use script with sed command in linux?

Tags: sed, cat, tail, head

How can I use the `sed` command (in Linux) to find the 1000th line in a file with 10000 lines and replace just that one line with another?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
sed '1000 s/foo/bar/' file.txt
```

Comment: Its working.. now i can roll up.. thnx for the answer