# Modify a part of a line on a file

Tags: bash, shell, file, line

I'm doing a script that should modify the value of a variable on a file which looks like something like that :

```
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = triton.itinet.fr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = triton, localhost.localdomain, localhost

relayhost = smtp.free.fr
home_mailbox = Maildir/

virtual_mailbox_domains = $myhostname
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I want to modify the value of relayhost by the user entry, I have done this

```
    modify_relayhost ()
{
    read new_relayhost
    if (test -e /etc/postfix/main.cf)
    then
        grep "relayhost" /etc/postfix/main.cf | cut -d= -f1 && echo $new_relayhost
    fi    
}
```

But it does not modify the file, it just print me that value called relayhost and write the user's one on the prompt

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single sed command:

```
read new_relayhost

sed -i.bak -E 's/^([ \t]*relayhost[ \t]*=[ \t]*).*/\1'"$new_relayhost"'/' /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

This `sed` command finds `relayhost` key surrounded by optional spaces and replaces it's value part with value of variable `$new_relayhost`.

Answer (score 1):

This simple `bash` script could do the trick. Am using the `read` command to read the user prompt and `sed` for replacement

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter relayhost value: " relayhost

if [ -f /etc/postfix/main.cf ];
then
    sed -i.bak -r "s/(relayhost *= *).*/\1$relayhost/" /etc/postfix/main.cf
fi
```

Running the script now

```
$ bash script.sh
enter relayhost value: abcd
$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = triton.itinet.fr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = triton, localhost.localdomain, localhost

relayhost = abcd
home_mailbox = Maildir/

virtual_mailbox_domains = $myhostname
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
host='new.host'

perl -pi.orig -e 's/^(\s*relayhost\s*=).*$/\1'"$host"'/' /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

With `-p` option, `perl` acts like a filter similar to *grep*, or *sed*. It actually adds `while (<>)` loop that reads the input line by line, and prints the result (to the file, due to `-i` option).

The `-i.orig` option creates a backup copy of the original file (`main.cf.orig`), and modifies the file in-place.

The [substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) is applied for each line in the file. It captures the left part (`\s*relayhost\s*=`) and joins it with with the new value (`$host`).

Note that the substitution is applied for the first match only. If you want to replace all occurrences of the variable, use the `g` modifier.