# how to edit a text file without editing other lines (cmd)

Tags: windows, text, cmd, edit

First, I'm in Korea. So my English will very bad.

I want to edit third line with out touching first line and the second line.

Before:

```
echo sample
echo sample
echo sample
echo sample
```

After:

```
echo sample
echo sample
echo hello
echo sample
```

Just like this.
without using this command:

```
echo echo sample> test.txt
echo echo sample> test.txt
echo echo hello> test.txt
echo echo sample> test.txt
```

So, I mean is not write 1,2,4's 'echo' and 'sample' things.
Only the third line's 'echo'.
What can I do?

Comment: I suggest you [install cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and then you can use standard *nix tools such as sed and awk, which makes tasks like this very simple.

Comment: it's not possible to "edit" a file in `cmd`. You have to read and rewrite the whole file line by line (with a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question here:

[bash: replace an entire line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file)

In your case, the command to use is:

```
sed -i '3s/.*/echo hello/' test.txt
```

Comment: sorry, but I'm talking about the windows command prompt.  It's not working.
can you know about the windows command prompt command?

Answer (score 0):

This will edit the 2nd line in C:\test.txt, just change the 3rd line down to the line number you want to edit.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=1
for /f %%a in (C:\test.txt) do (
if !i!==2 (
echo your new line >>C:\test2.txt
) else (
echo %%a >>C:\test2.txt
)
set /a i+=1
)
del C:\test.txt
ren C:\test2.txt test.txt
```

Comment: this will ignore empty lines.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, but I'm going by the OP's example, unless they say otherwise it might not have any

Comment: was just a note. If any noob stumbles across this answer you can be sure he has some empty lines in the wrong place... :)

Comment: @Stephan Haha yeah no doubt! :)

Comment: @Korean Sorry, yes you're right it's the wrong line, glad it's working though! :)

Comment: Sorry, it works in 2nd line, but I can't understand how to change other lines. I changed the "set=i(number)" but It didn't worked... Do you know this?