# Bash replace or create line in file

Tags: string, bash

What would be the best way of going about this.

If a line starts with a string, replace that whole line with new string
If no line in the file starts with that string, append it to the file

Ex:

file.txt:

```
FOO=blah
BAR=bleh
GIN=blop
```

How can I replace the FOO line if it exists or append to the file if no line starts with FOO?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Possible [Duplicate] for [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file-by-line-number)

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. That's "by line number" so not a very good dupe.

Comment: Try this: `grep 'FOO' file || echo 'FOO=blah' >> file`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command,

```
if grep -q -F 'FOO' file.txt ; then sed -i 's/FOO/newline/g' file.txt; else echo newline >> file.txt; fi
```

or (depending or your version of sed)

```
if grep -q -F 'FOO' file.txt ; then sed -i '' 's/FOO/newline/g' file.txt; else echo newline >> file.txt; fi
```