# How to replace a matrix entry in a text file with a number from another text file (OSX Sierra, bash)

Tags: bash, text, sed, replace, io

[How to replace an entire line in a text file by line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file-by-line-number/11145362)

The question at the link above asks how to replace a line in a text file.  nakeer (second answer from bottom) has provided an answer that works well for me as a Mac user:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/text-on-line-to-be-changed.*/text-to-replace-the=whole-line/' file-name
```

However, I cannot figure out how to modify it for my particular situation.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

1. I have many files. Each file contains this matrix, exactly as appears below:

   ```
   12.345678    0.000000    0.000000    
    0.000000   12.345678    0.000000    
    0.000000    0.000000   12.345678
   ```
2. I have one additional file that contains a column of numbers, like:

   ```
   87.654321   
   18.765432    
   21.876543
   ...
   ```
3. I want to take one number from each line of the column in (2).  I want to use it to replace the non-zero values of one matrix in (1) (preserving the zero values).  So the first matrix in the first file should look like:

   ```
   87.654321    0.000000    0.000000    
    0.000000   87.654321    0.000000    
    0.000000    0.000000   87.654321
   ```

The second matrix in the second file should use "18.765432" for its non-zero values.

4. I'm not experienced as far as bash scripting, but I so far have (where ic is my file in (1) that contains the original matrix and I copy it into a new directory where I can change that matrix to (3)):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   let timesteps=20000
   for ((step=0; step <= timesteps ; step++))
   do
     mkdir $step/results
     cp ic $step/ic

     cat X >> X # <--Here I'd like to modify nakeer's expression. Any hints would be much appreciated.
   ```

---

Update:

1. I have managed to get Ed's very clear solution up and running.  There is one problem, however.  The files that contain the matrices (see (1) above) also contain other data.  For example (before executing Ed's code):

> ```
>     12.345678    0.000000    0.000000    
>      0.000000   12.345678    0.000000    
>      0.000000    0.000000   12.345678
>    0.5   
>    abc.xyx 
>    90
>    900
>    0.125
>    90
>    6
> ```

Ed's code successfully changes `12.345678` in the matrix to a new value. However, `0.125` in the list of numbers below the matrix is also changed to that new value.  I do not want `0.125` to be changed.

Ed's code following `match` seems to use the format of numbers to identify which numbers to change and it looks like `0.125` falls into the category of numbers that should be changed.  If anyone has any ideas about how to exclude `0.125` from the change, I'd be grateful to know!

2. How can I modify Ed's code in the case that each matrix file is in its own directory; e.g., `0/file0, 1/file1, 2/file2`, etc?

Comment: Are you trying to replace all but non `0.0` values ? Or always the diagonal ? Which pattern is correct, if there is any ?

Comment: @Zelnes, hi, thanks for asking.  Yes, I'm always trying to replace the diagonal (all non-zero values).  I need to preserve the zeroes.

Comment: You can't just create the matrix while reading the file2 ? Instead of replacing

Comment: @Zelnes, if that's possible, then it sounds like a solution.  However, I create the new file (with the matrix values I want to change) by copying an original file.  So I would have to either change the original matrix during the copy process or change it after copying the original file as I have suggested in my question.  I have to be very careful only to change the matrix number and preserve all other formatting because the file will be an input file for an old code that is has strict formatting requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  numbers  tst.awk
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[NR]=$1; next }

FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME ".new"
    fileNr++
}

match($0,/[0-9.]+[1-9][0-9.]+/) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[fileNr] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}

{ print > out }
```

.

```
$ tail -n +1 numbers file*
==> numbers <==
87.654321
18.765432
21.876543

==> file1 <==
12.345678    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   12.345678    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   12.345678

==> file2 <==
12.345678    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   12.345678    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   12.345678

==> file3 <==
12.345678    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   12.345678    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   12.345678
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk numbers file1 file2 file3
```

.

```
$ ls
file1  file1.new  file2  file2.new  file3  file3.new  numbers  tst.awk
```

.

```
$ tail -n +1 file*.new
==> file1.new <==
87.654321    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   87.654321    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   87.654321

==> file2.new <==
18.765432    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   18.765432    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   18.765432

==> file3.new <==
21.876543    0.000000    0.000000
 0.000000   21.876543    0.000000
 0.000000    0.000000   21.876543
```

If you install GNU awk then you can use `-i inplace` to do "inplace" editing instead of creating new output files if that's useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation.  I managed to get it working and will now figure out how to make it work with the fact that my files (file1, file2, and file3, etc) reside in distinct directories.  One minor issue is that each file contains a list of other numbers below its matrix.  I see that one of the numbers (a decimal/float--the others are all ints) is changed to the same value that the matrix entries are changed to.  If anyone has any thoughts on how to prevent that, it would be great to hear them.  Very grateful, Ed.

Comment: You're welcome. It's very important when posting questions asking for help to manipulate data that you post sample input/output that's truly representative of that data. Edit your question to provide that better/more realistic example instead of what you have posted if you'd like help parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Zelnes 's idea, here's a version that just generates a new file based on your file2 data:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read value ; do
    ((fileNum++))
    awk -v input="$value" '
      END{
        for (i=1;i<4;i++) {
          for (j=1;j<4;j++) {
            #dbg print "#dbg: i=" i "\tj=" j;
            if (j==i) {
              #dbg print "#dbg: matched"
              arr[i]=input
            } else {
              #dbg print "#dbg: setting arr["j"]="arr[j]
              arr[j]=0.0
            }
          }
          printf("%0.6f\t%0.6f\t%0.6f\n",arr[1],arr[2],arr[3])}} ' /dev/null \
       > file"$fileNum".txt
done < newValues.txt
```

The `printf` can be changed to get the exact spacing you need for your format issues.
Change the `newValues.txt` at the end to the name of your real input file. You can even make that `/path/to/someplace/else/newValues.txt`.

You'll need to

```
chmod +x myDataGenerator
```

Before running it.

`cd` to the directory you want the files created in, then call the script with its full path i.e.

```
/full/path/to/myDataGenerator
```

If you want the tiniest program possible, remove the `#dbg`lines.

If you want to understand how the script works, uncomment one `#dbg` line at a time, understand what is is doing and **then** uncomment the next `#dbg`.

IHTH

Comment: @shelter, thank you very much.  I have nearly managed to get Ed's solution up and running, but yours sounds like it will help with another issue on my to-do list.  I'm trying to make a wrapper for an old FORTRAN code.  I'm fine with that, but this formatting (bash, Awk) stuff is way out of my comfort zone.  Thank you all very much for your help.