# sed not working on large files. Any suggestions on different ways or syntax changes for replacing strings

Tags: sed, replace

Trying to insert a line feed on large files in UNIX when a text string matches. Any file around 1GB or less, it works. Anything over that size, it does not complete the replace. It appears to do nothing.

I'm using the following command:

```
sed -i 's/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}{"active": true/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true/g' filename.txt
```

I have even tried:

```
sed 's/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}{"active": true/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true/g' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

Any other suggestions to add the line feed using any other command or syntax with sed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is the biggest file? How long does it take the command to run for 1 GB file?

Comment: the size of the files can vary.  I ran it on a 1.01 GB file and it ran in less than 1 minute.  Other files were 2.92 GB, 3.17 GB and 4.1 GB.  When I ran the command against these files, it ran for 1-2 minutes but the files were not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, which accomplishes what you need:

```
perl -i -pe 's/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"[}][{]"active": true/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true/g' filename.txt
```

Note that curly braces: `{` and `}` have special meaning to the regex engine, so you need to escape them like so: `\{` and `\}`, or put them into character classes like so: `[{]` and `[}]`. If you run the command as you have shown it, without escaping or character classes, it will not replace what you think it does (in Perl, at least).

Takes about 5 min for a 40 GB file on M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: I got an error.

Out of memory!

How can I resolve this?  Is it a laptop environment or a unix environment issue?

I tried it on a smaller file and it does indeed work.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the entire file is a single long line? See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44811130/967621

Comment: Yes, its a JSON file that got outputted as a single string.  I'm trying to put the line feeds between the messages.

Answer (score 0):

If occurrence of your string is frequent enough that records fit in memory, with GNU awk:

```
gawk \
    -v  RS='"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}{"active": true' \
    -v ors='"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true' \
    -v ORS= \
'
    NR>1 { print ors }
    1;
' filename.txt > filename.txt.new &&
mv filename.txt.new filename.txt
```

Note that `RS` is a regular expression, not a simple string.