# Remove a Line With Brackets At Beginning

Tags: sed

I need to remove a line which starts like this:

```
[success] Total ....
```

I tried the following sed command but it didn't work

```
sed '/\[/d' filename > newFile
```

But when I greped the new file the line is still there! What is the correct command to get rid of it

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This works as expected for me. Are you using gnu sed ? Or an other version on macOS/Windows ? Note that with gnu sed you can use the '-i' option to overwrite the file in place (does not handle backups): `sed -i '/\[/d' filename`

Comment: No I'm using Linux GNU sed. I have no idea why it is not working. The file is 10GB in size though. Maybe it can't handle it

Comment: To my knowledge, you only get problems with sed when your lines in your file are extremely long. For the rest, it streams the content so filesize should not be a problem. Anyway, you should get an error if it cannot handle it.

Comment: wrt `it didn't work` - never just say **that**. Tell us in what way it didn't work (wrong output, no output, error message, core dump, etc.) and post any error messages. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input (with the target line(s) **in context**) and expected output and the actual output you're getting

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting to delete a line that starts with a pattern, then you should use the anchor symbol (`^`) in the beginning of the pattern :

```
sed -E '/^\[/d' filename > newFile
```

To accommodate blank spaces in the beginning of the pattern which is common as a result of indentation, you should do

```
sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]+\[/d' filename > newFile
```

`GNU sed` has an inplace-edit option realized thru `-i` option, so above could be replaced by

```
sed -Ei '/^[[:blank:]]+\[/d' filename
```

It  seems that `sed` has [no limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951714/1620779)  concerning file size but it  is typically  slow for a large file.

Comment: `+` will not work without `-E`, which is a GNU extension. even if you escape it, it's not a part of POSIX BREs

Comment: @oguzismail I have only worked with GNU sed that I often forget about other versions. You have a point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a line starting with [ we can use this sed pattern

```
$ sed -E '/^\s*\[/d' filename
```

Say for file data3.txt having this content:

```
$ cat data3.txt
dont remove this line
[success] faile ... remove this line
[hola to be removed
[hola] remove this
 [hola]  remove this
[] remove thisline
this [success] Total dont remove this
```

You can run this command which takes care of blank/tab/space etc. at the beginning followed by [ and other text data:

```
$ sed '/^\s*\[/d' data3.txt
dont remove this line
this [success] Total dont remove this
```

Here

```
'/^\s*\[/d' : takes care of [ preceded by zero or more occurrences of space/tab etc.
```

Comment: As I understand, `-E/-r` has no effect on `*`, `[` or `]` but only on `?`,`+`,`{`,`}` and `|`. In GNU sed the latter list can be made _special_ by preceding each by `\\` without the need for former option.

Comment: @potong you are right, -E has no effect on *. edited my answer. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[[]' file
```

To match the `[`, I normally put it into a character class:

```
[]  # empty character class
[[] # character class with [ as the only item
```

Btw: If there are optional spaces allowed at the beginning of the line:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*[[]' file
```