# Strange error from data.table::fread using sed

Tags: r, data.table

I think this is an accurate title but feel free to change it if anyone thinks it can be worded better. I am running the following commands using `data.table::fread`.

```
fread("sed 's+0/0+0+g' R.test.txt > R.test.edit.txt")
fread("sed 's+0/1+1+g' R.test.edit.txt > R.test.edit2.txt")
fread("sed 's+1/1+2+g' R.test.edit2txt > R.test.edit3.txt")
fread("sed 's+./.+0.01+g' R.test3..edit3.txt > R.test.edit.final.txt")
```

After each line I get the following message

```
Warning messages:
1: In fread("sed 's+0/0+0+g' /R/R.test.small.txt > /R/R.test.edit.small.txt") :
  File '/path/to/tmp/RtmpwqJu82/file7e7e250b96bf' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
2: In fread("sed 's+0/1+1+g' /R/R.test.edit.small.txt > /R/R.test.edit2.small.txt") :
  File '/path/to/tmp/RtmpwqJu82/file7e7e8456d82' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
3: In fread("sed 's+1/1+2+g' /R/R.test.edit2.small.txt > /R/R.test.edit3.small.txt") :
  File '/path/to/tmp/RtmpwqJu82/file7e7e3f96bc35' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
4: In fread("sed 's+./.+0.01+g' /R/R.test.edit3.small.txt > /R/R.test.edit.final.small.txt") :
  File '/path/to/tmp/RtmpwqJu82/file7e7e302a3cde' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

So it is weird... fread makes all the files I need when I run it on my laptop but gives that error for each file. When I got to run the script on our cluster, the script crashes and gives the following message.

```
> fread("sed 's+0/0+0+g' /R/R.test.txt > /R/R.test.edit.txt")
Error in fread("sed 's+0/0+0+g' /R/R.test.txt > /R/R.test.edit.txt") : 
  File is empty: /dev/shm/file38d161d613c
Execution halted
```

I think it has to do with the message I get when I run the script on my laptop? I think it a user issue but maybe it is a bug. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas? I thought of a work around using the following

```
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time)
peakRAM(system(paste("sed 's+0/0+0+g' /R/R.test.txt > /R/R.test.edit.txt")),
system(paste("sed 's+0/1+1+g' /R/R.test.edit.txt > /R/R.test.edit2.txt")),
system(paste("sed 's+1/1+2+g' /R/R.test.edit2.txt > /R/R.test.edit3.txt")),
system(paste("sed 's+./.+0.01+g' /R/R.test.edit3.txt > /R/R.test.edit.final.txt")))
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time)
```

And this works fine. So I think there's a problem with sed or anything like that. I am just wondering what I am doing wrong when I use `fread`

Comment: This is because when you have "> newfilename" at the end, the command does not return anything, it simply creates a new file. This is why it's complaining about a size 0 file, you're asking fread to read the output of a command which doesn't output anything. Remove the "> newfilename" at the end and run that with fread.

Comment: If you want to create a new file, and not just read the output of the command straight into R, you would have to run the command with the "> newfile.txt" at the end as a system command outside of fread, then run `fread('newfile.txt')` in R.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan could you show an example? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Type `echo 'test' > newfile.txt` into the terminal. Nothing is printed. Why? Because you've redirected the output to a file instead. If you remove the `> newfile.txt` and just run `echo 'test'`, something is printed. What `fread` does is read the output of a command, i.e. what would be printed if you ran it in the terminal. Since these commands you're using print nothing, fread has nothing to read.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I get what you are saying now. Sorry, I guess I was just mentally fatigued from trying to fix the problem for so many hours. What I needed to do was just group the sed commands into one and just read the file into r instead of making separate files (which you suggested). When I run the following everything works great `df <- fread("sed -e 's+0/0+0+g' -e 's+0/1+1+g' -e 's+1/1+2+g' -e 's+./.+0.01+g' R/R.test.txt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments above are correct about what to do; I tried looking in the documentation for `fread` but didn't find anything helpful for you so I filed [an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3877) to improve... thanks!

When you pass a terminal command to `fread`, it creates a `tmp` file for you automatically in the background. You can see the exact line [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/0ba914488fbd21cf1c66006de4bdac29818e34cc/R/fread.R#L92), stylized:

```
system(paste0('(', cmd, ') > ', tmpFile<-tempfile(tmpdir=tmpdir))
```

Then `fread` is applied to that file. As mentioned, the file resulting from your command *with `> tmpFile` appended* has size 0.

If you actually want to keep those intermediate files (e.g. `R.test.edit.txt`), you have two options: (1) first, run `system('grep > R.test.edit.txt')` then run `fread` on the output; or (2) [available on development version only for now; see [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)] supply the `tmpdir` argument to `fread` and omit the `> R.test.edit.txt` part; `fread` will do the outputting itself for you.

If you don't actually care about the intermediate files, simply omit the `> R.test.edit.txt` part and `fread` should work as you were expecting, e.g.:

```
fread("sed 's+0/0+0+g' R.test.txt")
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and thanks for filing that issue! I don't care about the intermediate files and it makes it a lot easier not having them. I didn't realize you can combine sed commands into multiple edits. So when I run the following `df <- fread("sed -e 's+0/0+0+g' -e 's+0/1+1+g' -e 's+1/1+2+g' -e 's+./.+0.01+g' /R/R.test.txt")` everything works out great!