# Perforce pending changelist diff script

Tags: diff, perforce, patch

Does someone have such a script to share?

- takes a pending changelist number as input
- outputs a unified diff (including files open for add)

I know from experience many people who work with perforce all day have these kicking around. I could really use help with the whole issue of "file(s) not in client view" when diffing newly added files via "p4 diff".

Comment: I was looking for something like this: (http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/Creating+a+Patch+Review#CreatingaPatchReview-PerforcePatchCreationViaTheCommandLine or this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9522/automatic-patch-review-script-for-perforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't have the time to find a proper solution so I used this one liner:

```
p4 describe $CHANGELIST | sed -ne 's:^\.\.\. \(.*\)#[0-9][0-9]* [a-z][a-z]*$:\1:p' | xargs p4 diff -du
```

Here is how it works:

Since --

> ... Pending changelists are indicated as 'pending' and file diffs are not displayed.

```
p4 describe $CHANGELIST
```

by itself will not do, but you can use it as a starting point. It gets (among other things) a list of the files that was changed in your `$CHANGELIST`.

```
sed -ne 's:^\.\.\. \(.*\)#[0-9][0-9]* [a-z][a-z]*$:\1:p'
```

Prints the `<depot-file>` part of only the lines of the form `... <depot-file>#<revision> <action>`

```
xargs p4 diff -du
```

Takes the list of depot files and run `p4 diff -du` on it. The `-d` flag passes `u` (unified format) to your `$P4DIFF` program (that should be `diff`).

Comment: Does this work on windows, I get "sed" is not recognized command. How can I get a file diff (deletion and addition both included) in a colored format which i can send over via email to a peer for review?

Comment: `sed`, `xargs` and `diff` are typically present on a Unix-like systems. On Windows you can install 3rd party Unix-like utilities, or try to use the PowerShell. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/127318/110488

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
p4 diff2 //depot/a/b/c/... //depot/a/b/c/...@=$CHANGELIST | grep -v '<none>'
```

The more specific the path, the faster the execution.
You may also diff2 the changelist against a different branch.

Answer (score -1):

Does `p4 describe -du changelist` not work for you?

Comment: No, here is why: The script output would be a "diff" or "patch" (depending on your preferred terminology). The litmus test is "can it be fed to the unix patch utility to fully re-create the changes?" Notice that p4 describe does not include content of files "opened for add", so the patch would be missing all newly added files.

Comment: Ah, I see - as a workaround you can run 'p4 add' on the entire dir, and ignore the files that already exist.  A better solution (status command) is coming on the next release.  Once you know which files are added, you can dump their content into the patch.  So it will require a script I think.

Comment: `p4 describe` does not display any diff at all, even for modified files, if the changelist is pending.