# Replace all regex matches in a file

Tags: python, regex

Consider a basic regex like `a(.+?)a`. How can one replace all occurences of that regex in a file with the content of the first group?

Comment: This python tutorial site might be helpful: http://pythontesting.net/python/regex-search-replace-examples/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use can use the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) module to use regular expressions in python and the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module to simply replace text in files in-place

---

**Example:**

```
import fileinput
import re

fn = "test.txt" # your filename

r = re.compile('a(.+?)a')
for line in fileinput.input(fn, inplace=True):
  match = r.match(line)
  print match.group() if match else line.replace('\n', '')
```

---

**Before:**

> hello this
>   aShouldBeAMatch!!!!! and this should be gone
>   you know

**After:**

> hello this
>   aShouldBeAMa
>   you know

---

Note: this works because the argument `inplace=True` causes input file to be moved to a backup file and **standard output is directed to the input file**, as [documented under *Optional in-place filtering*](https://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput).

Comment: As a note to anyone who may be confused, `print` statements within that for loop are redirected to the file. (The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) for `fileinput` is quite good).

Comment: This works as intented, although im using `r.sub()` on the line to keep the non-matched parts of the line.

Comment: what is line.replace('\n', '') doing??  Where is the replacement text?  Please explain your code

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.5.html) with Version >= 6.0. Since then it does support PCRE Regex.

You can then use your regex `a(.+?)a` and replace with `$1`

Comment: He asked about doing it in Python

Answer (score -4):

#### sed

Are you limited to using Python tools? Because `sed` works very well.

```
$ sed -i <filename> "s/a(.+?)a/\1/g"
```

#### Vim

In a Vim window, give the following search-and-replace ex command:

```
:%s/\va(.+?)a/\1/g
```

Note that many regex characters are escaped in Vim- `\v` sets "very magic" mode, which removes the need for escaping. The same command with "magic" (the default) is `:%s/a\(.\+\?)a/\1/g`

#### Python

If you're looking to do this in Python, BigYellowCactus' answer is excellent (use the `re` module for regex, and `fileinput` to modify the file).

Comment: No, im Not but restricted  to Windows.

Comment: @Paranaix, you have [options to run `sed` on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/815632). Alternatively, you could perform a search and replace in Vim.