# replace string in txt using cmd

Tags: windows, string, cmd

I have a text file.

using windows cmd I want to find and replace the following

`__HTML_APP_URL__` --> `http://google.com`

Couldn't find simple tutorial to do so

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Answer (score 0):

I'll try

powerShell

`get-content somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"}`