# How do I lock a Perforce label from the command line?

Tags: command-line, locking, perforce, label

I recently imported a VSS repository into Perforce.  This included hundreds of labels, which the developer that was using VSS (now using Perforce) relies upon.  I accidentally deleted them and had to do the import again.  To prevent such accidental deletion in the future, I want to lock all the labels, but doing it through P4V would take forever.  I would like to write a script to do it for me.

I can get all the labels into a text file with the `p4 labels` command, and with some text editor macro processing I could build up a script to lock them all.  I just need to know the command(s) to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by automating the process of editing the label spec.  The process is as follows:

- Send the label spec to standard output with the -o switch.
- Pipe that output to a utility that can manipulate it and set the label's "Options" to "locked".  In this case, the Unix utility [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed) gets the job done.  (I'm on Windows, so I used [this port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/?source=dlp).  Others can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/4228).)
- Pipe this updated spec back into the label command with the -i switch.

Put it all together and you get a command that looks like this.

`p4 label -o <label name> | sed 's/^Options:.*/Options: locked/' | p4 label -i`

Answer (score 2):

The relevant Perforce doc is [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html).

To dump a label spec to standard output:

```
p4 -o *labelname*
```

To read a label spec from standard input:

```
p4 -i *labelname*
```

in between you'll need to process the text to include the 'options: locked' probably by redirecting standard output to a text file e.g. ('p4 -o *labelname* > labelspect.txt'), process the text file in your chosen manner, and then read the file into standard in ('p4 -i *labelname* < labelspect.txt')