# How to do a "sed -" like operation on Windows?

Tags: windows, unix, sed

I have a large 55 GB file in which there is a sentence on every line.
I want to check if there are any lines that have a dot "." at the end, and then if there is, I want to insert a space before the dot in that line.

Ex: I like that car.
Replace with: I like that car .

A space before the trailing dot on every line if there is a dot.

I don't have any cygwin or unix and I use a windows OS. Is there a sed like common that I can do on this 55GB! file?

I tried GetGNUWin32 but I am unable to determine the actual command there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Perl.  Strawberry Perl is probably the best distribution for Windows.  http://strawberryperl.com/

To do what you're talking about in Perl, it would be this:

```
perl -p -i -e's/\.$/ ./' filename
```

Comment: i tried and it didnt do anything on windows 7, after some experimenting i found that i had to use double quotes " instead of singe quotes '.

Answer (score 3):

You can install  `Cygwin` and use `sed` from there. And here I found [**Sed for Windows**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

---

**Edit**:
     Very Good Answers to your Question: 
    [**Is there any sed like utility for cmd.exe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe)

<sub>(I always prefix `stackoverfloew` when I search on google. Same I did for you on google: `sed on window stackoverflow`, but that is different matter)</sub>

Comment: For Google, you can add the inurl or site operators as well, @GrijeshChauhan

Answer (score 2):

**For your use case:**

From PowerShell.exe (comes with Windows)

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -Replace '\.$', ' .' | Set-Content file.txt
```

---

I searched for hours and hours and had so much trouble trying to find a solution to my use case, so I hope adding this answer helps someone else in the same situation.

For those who got here to figure out git filter clean/smudge like I did, here's how I finally managed it:

In file: `.gitconfig` *(global)*

```
[filter "replacePassword"]
    required = true
    clean = "PowerShell -Command \"(Get-Content " %f ") -Replace 'this is a password', 'this is NOT a password'\""
    smudge = "PowerShell -Command \"(Get-Content " %f ") -Replace 'this is NOT a password', 'this is a password'\""
```

Please note that this snippet doesn't change the original file (this is intended for my use case).

Additional search terms to help those looking: interpolation, interpolate