# GNU Plot: Plotting x, y, z values stored as one column

Tags: gnuplot

With GNU Plot, I normally process x, y, z data in three separate columns:

```
x1, y1, z1
x2, y1, z2
...
...
xn, yn, zn
```

and I used `splot 'filename.ext' with lines` to quickly get the a 3D plot

Due to our new system requirements, we have to store data in the following form:

```
x1
y1
z1
x2
y2
z2
.
.
xn
yn
zn
```

I already written a simple code in C# to transform our results into 3 columns for easy viewing in GNU Plot.

My question is, if the data is now only a one dimensional array, is there a way to plot this in GNU Plot directly without having my program to re-saved our results as a 3 columns results?

Thank you.

Regards,
ikel

**Additional info**: I am running on Win7, 64 bit, and using the Win binaries of GNU Plot. Apparently, I don't have `paste`, `sed` and `popen` (see discussion below).

Comment: Have a look at `every`. With some mock test data and an image of the desired output, we could try more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to make Gnuplot interpret the input as groups of three, but if your version of Gnuplot supports `popen`, you can join the lines on the fly with e.g. paste or sed:

```
splot '< paste - - - < filename.ext' with lines
```

Or:

```
splot '< sed "N; N; s/\n/ /g" filename.ext' with lines
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to run both of your commands and I ended up with `No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range. All points x value undefined.` I don't know if popen is available on my Windows distribution of GNU Plot.

Comment: @ikel -- Your gnuplot might not have `popen`, or alternatively, you might not have `paste` or `sed` installed.

Comment: Is there a way to install these features?

Comment: @ikel: There's a good [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) about installing sed on Windows, some of the suggested solutions also provide coreutils which paste is a part of. By the way [Gnuplot is not part of GNU](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00037000000000000000).

Comment: @Thor `splot '< sed "N; N; s/\n/ /g" filename.ext' with lines` works after installing cygwin, which provides access to `sed.` Thank you. This [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51) helped me to understand what your complete and minimalistic solution