# Batch - combining 3 columns of x, y, z values into 1 column without using MatLab

Tags: sed, multiple-columns

I have about 150 files containing 3 columns of x, y, z values and no header.

> x1 y1 z1
>
> x2 y2 z2
>
> x3 y3 z3
>
> ...
>
> xn  yn  zn

For our compress sensing algorithm, I need to have these values in one column only

> x1
>
> y1
>
> z1
>
> x2
>
> y2
>
> z2
>
> . . .
>
> xn
>
> yn
>
> zn

How could I perform this batch operation for 150 files, without using MatLab? From my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392411/gnu-plot-plotting-x-y-z-values-stored-as-one-column), I believe this could be done by using [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-61). But batch processing 150 files effectively is beyond my ability. I am running on Win7 with cygwin installed.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

ikel

**Edit: The delimiter is TAB**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have the files of interest in your present working directory, and, that the delimiter of your files is a single space, and, that you have `GNU sed` installed:

```
sed -i 's/ /\n/g' *
```

Alternatively, you could avoid `sed` and use `tr` and a `for` loop, like this:

```
for i in file*; do tr " " "\n" < "$i" > "$i.bak" && mv "$i.bak" "$i"; done
```

Comment: The delimiter happens to be a tab. That means I have to use `^I` instead of `s`? All files are in the same directory.

Comment: For a tab, use: `s/\t/\n/g`, which means substitute a tab for a newline, globally.