# Matlab: Plotting x, y, z values stored as one column

Tags: matlab, matrix

How should I accomplish [this plotting task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392411/gnu-plot-plotting-x-y-z-values-stored-as-one-column) task in Matlab?

Thank you.

EDIT:
What I am asking is how to plot in Matlab when the data are in one column as described in the link given above.

Regards,

ikel

Comment: `M = reshape(X,[],3)` should do the trick to get it into the format you expect based on the linked question.

Comment: @tmpearce I am using MatlabR2012b, I did that initially, but it didn't give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `reshape` and transpose the matrix and extract the columns:

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]';
reshaped_mat = reshape(vec,3,[])';
```

`reshaped_mat` will end up looking like this:

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

And you can extract the columns as follows:

```
x = reshaped_mat(:,1);
y = reshaped_mat(:,2);
z = reshaped_mat(:,3);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing that extra information on extracting the columns individually.

Answer (score 2):

You can  try something like this >

For example : A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6;7 8 9]

`A'` would be

```
     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9
```

First take the transpose,

```
B = A'
```

And convert it into a single column,

`B(:)` would give

```
ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think the questioner actually wants to go the other way: from a column to a `Nx3` matrix.

Comment: Oh, I might have got it wrong. Reshape would work right. By the time, I wanted to post it, there is already an answer.

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar upvoted, for giving me the keyword that I needed _"Transpose"_

Answer (score 2):

yet another option for the lazy user: given a vector `v`

```
 v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
```

since we know the elements go like `[x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...]` , plotting `x,y,z` will probably require `plot3`, so this is how it can be done directly:

```
 plot3(v(1:3:end),v(2:3:end),v(3:3:end))
```

where the entries are equivalent to

```
 x=v(1:3:end);
 y=v(2:3:end);
 z=v(3:3:end);
```

Comment: Thanks for your expertise. Before you called me `lazy` I plotted it by using `plot3()` by digging through examples and manual.

Comment: Oi! I see my humor did not go well... shame on me. by the way, by lazy i meant my solution (`v(1:3:end)` etc) ... did it at least help somewhat?

Comment: No hard feeling here. I simply didn't get your joke. Thanks for pointing out the `plot3()` and `v`. Your approach was indeed useful and `lazy`. Now that you mentioned it, a lecturer, Rob Miles, in his yellow book speaks of an aspect of programming as __Creativity Laziness__