# how to properly export an sql data to .csv

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to export a very large data from mysql to .csv and import the .csv into another identical table using the

```
into outfile
```

in phpmyadmin. But when i look at the excel file it is messed up. It seems that mysql cant determine the longtext format so it  goes to another line like this one:

[image]

So when i try to import this to an identical table, it is all messed up. Here's my import code to other table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'final.csv'
INTO TABLE oldforum_nodewithusers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

By the way i manually typed the headers of the table since i dont know too how to put headers in the export code. Here's my export code:

```
SELECT 'some table columns'
into outfile 'final.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

So how to fix this? is it in the export part? or the import part?

**I KNOW NOW THE PROBLEM, THEY TEXT THAT WENT TO THE NEXT LINE IN THE PICTURE HAS EXCEED THE TEXT LIMIT FOR A CELL IN EXCELL**

so when i import it to another table the table will treat the "next lined" text as another row. Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: What is preventing you from using a single insert query and skipping the part with the file?

Comment: they in a different database.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a command line approach (which has worked fine for me). On Linux (and other Unix systems):

```
$ mysql [connection parameters] yourDB -e"select..." | sed 's/\t/,/g' > yourOutput.csv
```

---

**Explaining**

- The `[connection parameters]` piece must include: `-h YourHost` (where `YourHost` must be a valid IP adress or server name, or `localhost`), `-u YourUser` and `-pYourPassword` (notice that you must not leave spaces between `-p` and `YourPassword`)
- `mysql ... -e"select..."` outputs the query result to standard out (your console) separating fields with tabs (`\t`).
- `| sed 's/\t/,/g'` replaces all tabs (`\t`) with commas. It takes the output from the previous command for processing, and also outputs the result to standard out
- `> yourOutput.csv` redirects the output of the previous command to a file instead of the console

---

**A windows option**

As far as I know, there's no "native" alternative to `sed` in Windows. But you can install Cygwin, which has "windows command-line compatible" features that replicate most of the Linux functionality. Also you may want to take a look to GnuWin32, which has an implementation of `sed` (among other things)

I also found an alternative in [Is there any sed like utility for cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) to create a VBScript similar to `sed`, you may want to check it out.

---

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this trick to get the headers:

```
select col1, col2 . . . -- export columns go here
into outfile . . .
from ((select 1 as isheader, 'Col1' as col1, 'Col2' as col2, . . .    -- headers go here
      ) union all
      (select 0 as isheader, col1, col2, . . . . -- data goes here
      )
     ) t
order by isheader desc
```

In practice, removing the `order by` will probably also work:

```
select *
into outfile . . .
from ((select 'Col1' as col1, 'Col2' as col2, . . .    -- headers go here
      ) union all
      (select col1, col2, . . . . -- data goes here
      )
     ) t
```

MySQL does not guarantee that the headers will go first, but they do in practice.

Also, to do this, make sure that your columns are properly converted to the string format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

OMG im so dumb. The answer is very simple, instead of exporting it to a .csv file i exported it to .sql. LOL Very simple and easy