# Find text and Replace for filename on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a bunch of files that I have in line 7(using notepad++) this:

```
name: word
```

And I want to replace that word with the filename without the file extension .yml (the filename have just the dot from the extension, example: filename.yml), so when replaced it looks like this:

```
name: filename
```

Can anyone help me since I have no knowledge with find/replace variables on notepad++?

Examples:

```
name: tower
name: house
name: building
name: marcus
name: john
```

Comment: Post an example of your data from line 7 or whatever.

Comment: regex in notepad++ can't "fetch" data from filenames, http, ftp or any other sources. You will need to hardcode it in the replace input. Otherwise you;ll need to create your own plugin.

Comment: is there anyway to be done in an easy way? other than notepad++?

Comment: @JPDayz Being a developer ain't easy. You can do it in almost anylanguage that has the ability to open/edit files. Also what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried nothing because i have no clue how to do it... i have no programming knowledge.

Comment: You could use command line tools like [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). Since you are a Windows user, check this [list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/2140859) of packages. Otherwise search google for any user-friendly Windows software being able to make such operations, I guess you will be able to find something without spending too much time learning regular expressions. Or you could see that as a good opportunity to learn a programming language (it's a rewarding experience after all!). If you sacrifice a whole day reading a Python tutorial for example, you could make it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this relatively simply by [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com). It allows you sending keystrokes/mouseclicks etc. so you can quickly perform actions which are else done manually. In this case, you can automate these manual steps by sending appropriate keypresses in Notepad++. Please learn how to do the following using keyboard and then simply send those keys via AHK.

1. menu `Edit` > `Copy to Clipboard` > `Current Filename to Clipboard` (<kbd>F10</kbd>, then arrows)
2. Open **Find/Replace** dialog (<kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>)
3. **Find what**: type `filename`
4. **Replace with**: send <kbd>ctrl+V</kbd> (paste) into this field so filename from clipboard gets pasted
5. send 4 backspaces to delete file extension and dot (if your extension has 3 characters)
6. press **Replace All** button (<kbd>Alt+A</kbd>)

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354) for some details of AutoHotKey use with Notepad++.