# Regex in Notepad ++ or Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

Using Notepad ++, Dreamweaver or some other editor,
is it possible to use a regex which uses file name in the replace field?

For example: 
There are files: `firstfile.html` and `secondfile.html`

```
Find: yyy
Replace: "some regex for files name"
```

And then in those files wherever `yyy` is found it will be replaced with the file's name.

In `firstfile.html` - if there is `yyy` it will be replaced with `firstfile`.

In `secondfile.html` - if there is `yyy` it will be replaced with `secondfile`.

Comment: [Same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840541/find-text-and-replace-for-filename-on-notepad), basically you can't without writing a plugin or using an altogether other language/tool.

Comment: Make a tool to do this, and you can use it again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for "some other editor", the answer is yes ([EditPad](http://www.editpadpro.com) can do this):

[image: EPP screenshot]

(I removed some parts of the user interface to save space in this screenshot).

Comment: There is a problem. It really work BUT - it seems that all files must be open in order to do replace job. Is it possible it won't replace whole folder as dreamweaver for example? Folder contains a lot of files that need change I mean a lot... I'm new to editpad pro perhaps I miss something.... I download editp ro 7 free trial...

Comment: @user3082821: Right, EditPadPro only works on files opened in the editor. There'a different tool that works on folders/disks etc. (PowerGREP), but that's much more expensive. You could open all the files in your folder and click on the "Files" option in the regex search/replace panel to tell EPP to apply the regex to all the opened files.

Comment: Your solution with editpad pro is good. I know your name on this site from other questions. I think, if I remember other topics, that you are expert for regex problems. Thank you very much for your help. Just to mention I download PowerGrep but I can not find replace field.

Comment: Can you please check the link below :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294441/rename-file-name-using-some-text-from-that-same-file