# Size of the sorted file is double than original file in powershell

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I have a powershell script, that reads file content, sorts it and writes output to new file. Following is the script:

get-content $inputFile | sort > $sortedFile

The output in file is sorted properly, but the output file ($sortedFile) is double larger than input file ($inputFile). Note: There are no duplicate or extra line in output file.

Any help or ideas regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely the input file is `ascii` encoding while the default output using redirection is `unicode` encoding.

Instead of using `>` as redirection you can use [out-file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) and specify an encoding.

`get-content $inputFile | sort | out-file -encoding ASCII`