# SED type functionality in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd, extract

I have the following SED command:

```
sed -n /"PartA/,/PartB/p" Input.txt > Output.txt
```

Essentially, I am using this to extract any bunch of text between PartA &  PartB in the Input.txt file and write it to Output.txt

Is there any way I can do this without the use of SED , since SED is not native to windows.

So i have a log file that has a lot of text with something like this:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
PARTA
123
456
PARTB
JKL
MNO
PQR
PARTA
789
PARTB
STU
VWX
```

I want the output to look like this

```
PARTA
123
456
PARTB
PARTA
789
PARTB
```

Comment: You can install `cygwin` which brings many unix-like tools to MS Win. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/127318/1030675

Comment: That's true. But I don't want to install any extra tools. Just wondering if this functionality could be achieved using the existing windows capability.

Comment: The command line utilities included with Windows aren't nearly as powerful as the ones included with Linux.

Comment: no much idea of SED. can you provide a sample input text and the expected output text?

Comment: `findstr /r` will do a regex search of a file.  Type `findstr /?` at the command line or search google for help using it.

Comment: I've added my sample input & output. Please let me know if that would be any help.

Answer (score 0):

use vbs or powershell script depending windows version. a bit of code but native on windows and regex are "available" in it