# Copy File with Regex Replacement

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, file-copying

I'm trying to find a simple/elegant command-line solution for a process that is often used in scripts.  Something like:  (Fictional example)

```
CopyWithReplace <SourceFile> <DestFile> -m <match regular expression> -r <replacement regular expression>
```

It would copy the text file with the matched text replaced as specified.  Ideally, the find/replace would happen in the pipeline, rather than as a secondary step.  (Destinations quite often are remote locations, and long distance WAN links are often not as fast and reliable as  desired.)

What would be the simplest** way to achieve this scriptable functionality in a windows environment?

** Simplest = easy to write batch code, fewest 3rd party tools, etc.  Bonus points for a reasonably standard Regex implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

The basic usage pattern, for a substitution as you described, is:

```
sed 's/regexp/replacement/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

`sed` is a Unix utility, but there are several ways of using it in Windows if you wish. [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/1954610) lists the various options available.