# Remove trailing whitespace in CSV before importing to Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, whitespace

I want to import a CSV file into my Postgresql database through a PHP page. Is there a way to preprocess the CSV file so as to remove the trailing whitespace other than writing to the database line by line?

Comment: sed will work just fine.

Comment: @wildplasser could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: on unix: `man sed` you need something like `sed 's/[ \t\r]*$//' <infile.csv >outfile.csv`

Comment: thanks. is there a solution for windows as well?

Comment: Windows was never intended to do actual programming.

Comment: Several ways of getting sed under Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe#127567

Comment: thanks I'll check it out @mlinth

Answer (score 0):

Since you already import the data with PHP, you can employ it for preparing the file as well. See [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for removing whitespace at both ends, or [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for trailing whitespace.

A simple loop does the job

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');
$tmp = fopen('/path/to/tmpfile.csv', 'w');
while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    $line = rtrim($line);
    fwrite($tmp, $line);
}

fclose($tmp);
fclose($fp);

// now you can import /path/to/tmpfile.csv
```