# How to call `sed` command from python on windows?

Tags: python-3.x

How to call `sed` command from python on windows?

On Linux, I can do it like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sed command")
```

How to do it on windows?

There is no `sed` on windows.

Comment: If it is an option to install a sed like command -
 there are some listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe  the alternative may be to rewrite the transformation that you are doing in sed in python

Comment: This sounds less like a question about python and more like a question about how to get `sed` on windows.