# Shell Script for modifying desktop.ini file

Tags: shell, batch-file, desktop.ini

I have many folders with custom icons. All the folders are present in same directory.
For eg. D:\Folder is the directory which contains folder1, folder2, ..... etc.
And each folder contain their respective icon and desktop.ini files

The contents of current desktop.ini file are as follows:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0
NoSharing=1
IconFile=folder1.ico
IconIndex=0
InfoTip=folder1
```

I want to remove **NoSharing=1** from each folder's desktop.ini file.
After Removal the ini file should look like :

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0
IconFile=folder1.ico
IconIndex=0
InfoTip=folder1
```

The ini file is hidden and has attributes : system, hidden and archive.
Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 1 command: Recursively(`-r`) replace/remove `NoSharing=1` line in each `desktop.ini` files in `D:\Folder`

`msr -r -p D:\Folder -f "^desktop.ini$" -S -t "(\s+)NoSharing=1\s*" -o "$1" -R`

- If you want to preview colorful replacing result, remove `-R`
- If you want to backup changed files, add `-K` like `-R -K` or `-RK`
- You can also filter by file name, directory name, size range, last write time range, etc., just run the exe to show built-in usages and docs, or see git docs like [README.md](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/README.md)

`msr.exe`/`msr.gcc*`/`msr.cygwin` is a single exe tool (about 1.6MB, no dependencies, with cross platform versions on Windows and Linux) to find and replace files or pipe text recursively and support backup: in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory.

[image: Replace files]

Comment: Since I am completely new to this. Can you tell me how to use this.

Comment: You're on Windows, right? so, download the [**msr.exe**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/raw/master/tools/msr.exe) (use `msr-Win32.exe` if your Windows is 32-bit).  To use it anywhere: **Method-1**: Save it into a directory like `d:\tools` and add `d:\tools` to your computer environment variable `PATH`.  **Method-2**: Copy `msr.exe` to `C:\windows\system32`.

Comment: Just run the exe you'll see the colorful usages and examples. Or else you can see online built-in docs like [**msr on Windows**](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html) and [**readme.txt**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/tools/readme.txt), or [**Vivid examples**](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/demo/windows-test.html). In fact, these're all from [**README.md**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) to `p`rint every line *except* the unwanted line, on all the filenames, (*MS Windows* style pathnames), with in-place editing and backup files:

```
sed --in-place=.bak --quiet '/^NoSharing=1$/!p' D:\Folder\folder?\desktop.ini
```

(Remove the `=.bak` if backups aren't needed.)

Comment: Sorry, but the **folders** name are not exactly folder1,2,3 etc, they are different. I used it for a general description. It would be very helpful if you could provide a way to access all the folder names. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sam1803, Re "*exactly folder1,2,3 etc*":  please specify if `D:\Folder\` contains *any* subfolders containing `desktop.ini` folders that should *not* be changed.

Comment: **D:\Folder** is the directory which contains many **_folders_** and these **_folders_** have _desktop.ini_ files.