# Delete line from all the files in a folder with string 'Generation'

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, sed

I want to delete a line with string 'Generation' in all the files under a folder named KCG. I tried the following in Windows OS command prompt:

```
sed -i '/Generation/d' file
```

But got the following error message:

```
sed: can't read file: No such file or directory
```

Next I tried:

```
sed -i '/Generation/d' airport_related_altitudes_derived_data.c
```

This worked, but I do not want to enter the filenames of all the files in the folder each time. Is there a command to recursively look for the string in all the files under the folder?

Comment: Please include your code as text, and [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: sed and single quotes lets me assume a Linux OS - then the tag batch-file is wrong.

Comment: @LotPings: No I am using windows OS. I do not know the right syntax. Could you please suggest the right syntax for windows OS?

Comment: Normally replace single quotes (which have no special meaning in batch) with double quotes. My sed variant errors out with inplace edit (Gnu sed 4.1.2) but there are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/6811411).

Comment: @LotPings: You mean the syntax is sed -i "/Generation/d" file?

Comment: Yes, but `file` should be a real file name.

Comment: But that's my requirement(as posted in the description). I do not want to type filename of each file in the folder. Hence I would like to know if there is any syntax to recursively remove any line(s) with string Generation in all the files under a given folder.

Comment: Check if it works with a single file, in batch you'll use a `for` loop do iterate all files of a type.

Comment: @LotPings: As mentioned in my original post, it works for single file even if I use single quotes. But as I said earlier, I do not want to enter filename each time. I want a syntax that runs recursively for all the .c and .h files under a given folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/Generation/d' {} \;
```

That will recursively find all files ("-type f") under the current directory (".") and call "sed -i '/Generation/d'" on each file ("{}").

Comment: It did not work. Got an error message saying - FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: @user10564941, did you read the comment above from LotPings? The syntax you are using with `SED` tells us you are using a Linux which is why Anthony provided you a solutions using the `FIND` command from Linux. But the error message you just described in your comment tells me you are using Windows.

Comment: @Squashman: Hi Squashman, yes I did read LotPings comment and that is why I have added more information in my original description mentioning that I am using Windows OS. Hence could you provide me a syntax for windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

A **windows way** to enumerate files of a pattern/file type in current folder.

```
@Echo off
For %%A in (*.c) Do sed -i '/Generation/d' %%A
```

Recursive from a start path

```
For /r "X:\start\path" %%A in (*.c) do sed -i '/Generation/d' %%A
```

A pure batch way to drop lines containing words from a file is using `find /v` or  `findstr /v` but requires a different output file name, no inplace editing.

```
@Echo off
for %%A in (*.c) do findstr /vi "Generation" "%%~A" >"%%~dpnA_new%%~xA"
```

what creates new files with a appended `_new` before the extension.

It's of course possible to rename the old to .bak and write the changed version to the original name.

Comment: Which command and on cmd line or in a batch file? To test oput precede `sed` with an `echo sed ...`