# How to get a listing of files and folders withou part between parenthesis

Tags: batch-file, command, line, prompt

Hi I  would like to know if it is possible to get a listing of files and folders without the part between parenthensis by using the command prompt or a batch file.

When I use dir /b i get:

```
Lenovo 48394 Dual (48437873) Red
Lenoxx smoth 3030 (1545308)
Logitech razer 220 (04948393)
Microsoft V-3000x (4837483449) Black
```

But what I need is:

```
Lenovo 48394 Dual Red
Lenoxx smoth 3030
Logitech razer 220
Microsoft V-3000x Black
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To simply remove the `(.....)` part:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=()" %%a in ('dir /b') do echo %%a%%b
```

If the two spaces disturb you:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=()" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
  set "line=%%a%%b"
  echo !line:  = !
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really Win CMD solution, but if you could use the Windows Subsystem for Linux, the `sed` utility with regular expression replace will work.

```
sed -e 's/(.*)//g' input_file
```

this command reads input data from input_file and prints the result to the stdout. The `(.*)` regex matches any text between parenthesis and the parenthesis itself

UPD: It looks like you can use Windows Powershell. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028937/2169953)

Comment: Thanks but I need a Windows solution. About that powershell part I'm not sure how to use it for my needs I tried:
get-content somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "(*)",""}
with no success.

Answer (score 0):

---

> - When it is necessary to get parenthetical content (??) by removing only the parentheses:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title %~n0

for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /b "*.*" ^|find /v ".cmd"')do call :^[ "%%~i" && echo=!_str!
exit /b 

:^[
set _str=%~1
for /f ^tokens^=* %%S in ('cmd /c set /p "=%_str:)=%"^<nul')do call set _str=%%S
for /f ^tokens^=* %%S in ('cmd /c set /p "=%_str:(=%"^<nul')do call set _str=%%S
exit /b
```

---

I can suggest you to know unxutils, these are some linux executables already ported to Windows platform, including sed, less, cat, atil, etc..

Unxutils is available on this site: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net

So, try the @Bragnikita answer (tested) in for loop!

```bat
for /f ^tokens^=* %i in ('dir /b "*.*" ^|find /v ".cmd"')do @echo/%i | sed -e "s/(.*)//g"
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe i need that some day.