# Windows cmd equivalent of sed command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a cmd script to parse the java version from the `java -fullversion` command. I am able to retrieve the version like that: `1.6.0_45`, `1.7.0_60`, `1.8.0_212`, `11.0.4`. I would like to return the versions as `6`, `7`, `11`. As you can see not all of these appear before the first dot.

I have found the following sed command that works and would like to know the windows cmd equivalent:

```
sed '/^1\./s///'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any sed like utility for cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe)

Comment: @Martin, but that's not really an answer to this question. This is about trying to do the same as this specific `sed` command in `cmd`, not about finding a different tool that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a few parts, some of which aren't really nice to do:

1. Get Java's output in a variable

   ```
   for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%v in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "version=%%v"
   ```

   This only retains the part between the quotes, in my case `11.0.4+11`.
2. The `sed`-like part, which is rather easy:

   ```
   if "%version:~0,2%"=="1." set version=%version:~2%
   ```

   Basically just "if the first two characters are `1.`, cut them off`.
3. Cut off everything starting with the first `.`:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%v in ("%version%") do set version=%%v
   ```

   This again uses `for /f` for parsing and tokenizing and only retains the first token.

Generally these days you can probably use PowerShell as well:

```
"$(java -fullversion 2>&1)" -replace '.*?([\d.]+).*','$1' -replace '^1\.'
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#   Invoke Java and          Replace everything but the    sed equivalent
#   capture stderr           version
```