# Batch Script - Add Column to CSV based on Filename

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a directory where several CSV are in, and the CSV file names are all like this:

```
prod_EU_30.csv
prod_US_30.csv
prod_CHN_30.csv
prod_UK_30.csv
```

etc.

For every CSV file automatically, how can I add a column with the region name to the according CSV file and add the region name as content for each line in this newly created column? For example, let's take the first one: I would like to have a column `EU` to `prod_EU_30.csv` and fill this newly created `EU` column with `EU` for each line of the CSV.

Comment: Please describe more your environment - operating system, available scripting tools or languages. Task can be solved in many ways and it's not clear what fits to your situation. If I were you, I would use linux shell tools (namely `for` loop combined with `sed` used to extract country from file name and another `sed` to append column to the end of each line in CSV), though I fully understand other guy would prefer Visual Basic Excel macro :-).

Comment: @TomášZáluský Unfortunately Linux is not an option in this case. Operating system is Windows 10 and we have to operate with CSVs. The CSVs are all comma separated.

Comment: Then you can either use Powershell or install some Windows port of sed. You can find a lot of inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe . If you are not familiar with any of these tools and number of your files is under say 20, it will probably be faster for you to edit in Notepad manually one at a time.

Comment: Your question requires more focus, if you wish it to receive appropriate attention. Please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59422250/edit) to include, examples of the CSV content, now and afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

> This answer and code considering:

- **1)** the bat are and run in same folder where the .csv files are
- **2)** you not need use recursively for look and apply edit the .csv files
- **3)** you also need add the Region Name in first line off all files .csv
- **4)** definitely my English is worse than i thought, and limit to me explain more, sorry!..

If  you look for pure bat solution, and if your  delimiter is ";", may this can help to do this job for you:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion && cd /d "%~dp0" && title .\%~nx0

for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where .:*.csv')do (set "_csv=%%~fitmp"
cmd.exe /v/c <nul type nul >"!_csv!" && for /f tokens^=^2^delims^=_ %%z in ('
echo="%%~ni"')do set "_r=Region Name"&& for /f tokens^=*^delims^=^; %%I in ('
type "%%~fi"')do echo=!_r!| find "Region N" >nul && (echo=%%~I;!_r!>>"!_csv!"
set "_r=")||(echo=%%~I;%%~z>>"!_csv!"))&& move/y "!_csv!" "!_csv:~0,-3!" >nul
endlocal & exit /b
```

---

> - Sample File prod_EU_30.csv Test Layout:
>
>   ---

```bat
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N
2;3;3;4;4;5;5;6;6;7;7;8;8;9
.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.
n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n
.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.
6;7;7;8;8;9;9;0;0;1;1;2;2;3
```

---

> - Sample File prod_EU_30.csv Test Layout Results:
>
>   ---

```bat
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;Region Name
2;3;3;4;4;5;5;6;6;7;7;8;8;9;EU
.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;EU
n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n
.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;.;EU
6;7;7;8;8;9;9;0;0;1;1;2;2;3;EU
```

---

> - **Obs.:** If your delimiter is not "`;`", replace the correct one
>
>   ---

---

> - If you don´t need add "Region Name" in first line, try:

---

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & cd/d "%~dp0" && title .\%0

for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where ".:*.csv"')do (
  set "_f=%%~fitmp" && for /f tokens^=^2^delims^=_ %%z in ('
     echo="%%~ni"')do for /f tokens^=^*^delims^=^; %%I in ('
                    type "%%~fi"')do echo=%%~I;%%~z>>"!_f!")
                            move /y "!_f!" "!_f:~0,-3!" >nul
                                         endlocal && exit /b
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It's not batch, it's a command line utility (for Linux, Max and Win). Using this Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) command

```
mlr -I --csv put '$regionName=FILENAME;$regionName=gsub($regionName,"^(.+)_(.+)_(.+)$","\2")' *.csv
```

You will have this output for every CSV file you have in the active folder.

```
+-----+-----+------------+
| foo | bar | regionName |
+-----+-----+------------+
| a   | z   | EU         |
| b   | y   | EU         |
+-----+-----+------------+
```

This script modify your source files, than use it on a copy of them.

Please note, I'm using CSV files that have `,` as separator.

Answer (score 0):

(untested)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (prod_*_30.csv) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%r in ("%%f") do (
    )for /f "delims=" %%a in (%%f) do (
      echo %%a,%%r
    ))>%%~nf.new
    ECHO move /y %%~nf.new %%f
  )
)
```

Note: I disabled the `move` command for security reasons. Remove the `ECHO` after verifying it does what you want.