# Dotnet - How to change Target Framework using CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

**How to change Dotnet
target framework in .csproj using CLI?**

I know how to do this using Visual Studio, but I want to do it using CLI.

Are there any commands like,
`dotnet changeframework netcoreapp3.1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built in command.

You can edit the `.csproj` file as a text file and modify the `TargetFramework` element directly.

You can override it at build time using the CLI by overriding the msbuild property: `dotnet build -p:TargetFramwork=netcoreapp3.1`.

You can use command line tools like `sed` (on Linux/macOS) to modify the file directly: `sed -i -E 's|<TargetFramework>.*</TargetFramework>|<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>|' file.csproj`. For Windows, try [`get-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028937/3561275).

Answer (score 3):

I have **net6.0** and **net5.0** installed on my machine, and the **default is set to net6.0**. I wanted to target net5.0 framework for a webapi project and achieved it by typing this: `dotnet new webapi -f net5.0 -n myApiProject`

You can also see all the options on any template by typing `dotnet new <template (example: webapi, classlib, etc.)> -h`. This is where I found the `-f|--framework` option.

Comment: For reference, this command is for making a _new_ project. There is still no way to modifying an _existing_ project using the CLI.