# Find and replace pattern in large number of files

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, batch-processing

I want to replace text in about 80.000 log files using a regex. I love the batch search and replace of VSCode. I was unable to do this with VSCode, because it did not seem to handle this amount of data well. Any suggestion how I could do this with VSCode? Are there suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: Notepad++ can handle any number of files and also has regex find-replace, or write a simple python script that uses a glob over the current directory

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending on a GUI-based tool, it may be easier to use a CLI tool for this.

If you're using Linux, or willing to install `sed` and `find` on Windows, then it should be relatively simple. They are both command line tools for performing these operations in the terminal.

Use `sed` to replace the matched pattern with a replacement, using the global modifier to match all results, and the file to do the replacement and overwrite:
`sed -i s/{pattern}/{replacement}/g {file}`

Use `find` to get items recursively starting from the current directory where its type is file, and it has a name ending with `.log`. Then use `sed` to replace the pattern with the contents you want for each matched file:
`find -type f -name "*.log" exec sed -i s/{pattern}/{replacement}/g {};`

You can learn how to install `sed` and `find` for Windows on the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/6277798

Comment: For anyone else new to `sed`, you need to add the `-E` flag for regular expressions to work. Also, double-quote and escape the replacement string. If you have a bang `!`, put it in single quotes within the double-quoted string. Eg, `find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -Ei '' "s/<"'!'"-- Some [^ ]+ string to remove -->//g" {} +` (tested on macOS 13).