# Remove cell tages when converting a jupyter notebook to a julia script

Tags: julia

I am wondering if there's a way to remove cell tags when converting a jupyter notebook to julia script. At the moment, I use the `Weave` package and it works fine except leaving some cell tags `#+` inbetween the lines of syntax. What's the best way to remove these `#+` and get a cleaner conversion?

```
julia> using Weave

julia> convert_doc("mynotebook.ipynb", "mynotebook.jl")
```

```
#+ 

using DataFrames
using Weave

#+
```

Answer (score 1):

These characters seem to be hardcoded ([source](https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl/blob/b1de7efedeca3f6c9ee1e72e3d340dc41bd4c752/src/converter.jl#L50)).

You could fork the repo and change this behavior or you could use some sort of command line utility on the converted file to remove every line where the `#+` characters exist and any other unnecessary newlines.

Let's say we have a notebook that looks like this:

[image: notebook]

This will be converted to this:

```
#+



#+

print("print from cell 2")


#+

print("print from cell 3")
```

We could use a tool like `sed` to delete all lines that start with `#+` using:

```
sed '/^#+/d' file.jl
```

This returns:

```
print("print from cell 2")



print("print from cell 3")
```

There are still a lot of newlines so we could use `cat -s` on this output:

> -s, --squeeze-blank
> suppress repeated empty output lines

```
sed '/^#+/d' file.jl | cat -s
```

Which returns:

```
print("print from cell 2")

print("print from cell 3")
```

We can overwrite the content of the file with this output:

```
sed '/^#+/d' file.jl | cat -s > file.jl
```

If you're on Windows and you don't have a sed like utility installed that you could apply above idea with, you could look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe).