# R2 in Brackets with Esttab

Tags: stata

I want to export my regression results in TeX format with R2 in brackets using esttab. The code below produces a table with no brackets around R2 and I couldn't find a way to add them.

```
sysuse auto
eststo: qui reg price mpg

esttab using "reg.tex", ///
compress noconstant replace gaps noobs ///
 b(%8.3f) se(%8.3f) r2(%8.3f) nolines
```

Comment: I recommend going on Statalist with this one. `esttab` is a great command I never use, so I stop there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible out-of-the-box with `esttab`. The second-best is to automate this via `sed` (if on Mac/Linux):

```
sysuse auto
eststo: qui reg price mpg

esttab using "reg.tex", ///
compress noconstant replace gaps noobs ///
 b(%8.3f) se(%8.3f) r2(%8.3f) nolines 

shell sed -i.bak -e 's#\\(R^{2}\\)#[R^{2}]#' reg.tex
```

On Windows it's possible to use `powershell` for this, but I don't have access to a Windows machine to test it. A good starting point for Windows could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028937/10693596).